# How to wp-query posts by category using the sql AND and OR operator

Tags: sql, wordpress

I would like to create basically a sql statement to the effect:

Select all posts from table where post has the following assigned categories as follows: (has category==7, or has category ==8 or has category ==9) and has both categories (category ==10 and category=33)  using wp-query. Note: numbers represent category ID.

I tried various wp-query category parameters.

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'category__and' => array(10,33),
 'category__in' => array(7,8,9),
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'posts_per_page'=> '-1', // overrides posts per page in theme settings
 );
```

Not errors just incorrect posts chosen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your response. This worked for me

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'category__and' => array(10,33),
 'cat' => 7,8,9
 'order' => 'ASC',
 'posts_per_page'=> '-1', // overrides posts per page in theme settings
 );
```